# Can't build Ionic App for iOS with Capacitor AdMob-plus

Tags: ios, swift, ionic-framework, admob, capacitor

I am currently trying to integrate AdMob-plus into my ionic/capacitor app. But I can't get it to build properly as soon as I install the AdMob-plus dependencies.

I am following the installation guide here: https://admob-plus.github.io/docs/capacitor

I installed the dependencies and also ran the capacitor sync command. Both worked without error. But as soon as I try to build the app via the CLI (or Xcode, doesn't really matter) I get this error:

```
[capacitor]         ** BUILD FAILED **
[capacitor]         
[capacitor]         
[capacitor]         The following build commands failed:
[capacitor]         CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/paul/projects/ionic/amazingday/node_modules/@admob-plus/capacitor/ios/Plugin/AMBBanner.swift (in target 'AdmobPlusCapacitor' from project 'Pods')
[capacitor]         CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'AdmobPlusCapacitor' from project 'Pods')
[capacitor]         (2 failures)
[capacitor]         
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
```

I also did add the GADApplicationIdentifier and the SKAdNetworkItems to the Info.plist file.

My Ionic CLI version is 6.18.1, my capacitor version is 3.3.1

I hope someone can shed some light into my issue!

Comment: Run the build in verbose mode, there are some missing components you need to install for iOS compilation.